# Why can't I call self.save! inside of a Ruby DataMapper after :create callback?

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

I have the following minimal example DataMapper model:

```
# model.rb
require 'data_mapper'

class Job
  include DataMapper::Resource
  after :create, :create_id_based_data

  property :id, Serial
  property :magicNumber, String

  def create_id_based_data
    self.magicNumber =  "#{self.id}_#{Random.rand()}"
    self.save!
  end
end

DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite::memory:')
DataMapper.auto_migrate!
```

If I run the code in irb, "magicNumber" is not saved to the database:

```
irb -r ./model.rb 
2.2.1 :001 > Job.all
 => [] 
2.2.1 :002 > Job.create
 => #<Job @id=1 @magicNumber="1_0.6245356525078689"> 
2.2.1 :003 > Job.all
 => [#<Job @id=1 @magicNumber=nil>]
```

My understanding is that DataMapper will prevent a repeated `save` call inside of a `save` callback, but shouldn't a `save` call be allowable inside of a `create` after hook?  And even if a normal `save` call is not allowed, shouldn't the `save!` call bypass all callbacks and therefore be allowable?

Comment: I am running datamapper v1.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this bug report](https://datamapper.lighthouseapp.com/projects/20609/tickets/1152), it appears the mechanism (`run_once`) that prevents a loop of `save` calls is still at play.  Not clear if this is a bug or not.  Using `save_self` gives the behavior you want, at the cost of using a semi-public API.

```
# model.rb                         
require 'data_mapper'

class Job
  include DataMapper::Resource
  after :create, :create_id_based_data

  property :id, Serial
  property :magicNumber, String

  def create_id_based_data
    self.magicNumber =  "#{self.id}_#{Random.rand()}" 
    save_self(false)
  end
end

DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite::memory:')
DataMapper.auto_migrate!
```

The result:

```
irb -r ./model.rb
2.1.0 :001 > Job.all
 => []
2.1.0 :002 > Job.create
 => #<Job @id=1 @magicNumber="1_0.7816860975338344">
2.1.0 :003 > Job.all
 => [#<Job @id=1 @magicNumber="1_0.7816860975338344">]
2.1.0 :004 >
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm confused by your last sentence. Are you agreeing with me, or are you saying that `save!` is behaving as one would expect?

Comment: I agree with you.  I expect `create` to change the datastore, which it is.  I'd expect a call to `save!` in the callback should also change the datastore.  I entered an issue to dm-sqlite-adpater on github.com, no comment yet.